# Show one google map one page one in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble getting two maps to work, one being in a bootstrap modal. I have tried other fixes such as resizing the map once the modal is loaded but I'm having no success.

I just need the modal one to work correctly, I don't mind altering any of the existing code.

```js
function initialize(mapNum) {
  var map;
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.676,-70.786);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
       
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"+mapNum), myOptions);
       
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map, 
    title:"Hello"
  });
}

initialize(1); 
initialize(2);

$('#mapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(54, -2));
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

```css
.map {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="map1" class="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal"><h4>Dialog Box Pop-Up Map</h4>    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mapModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title text">Map</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <div id="map2" class="map"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-fresh" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wouldn't it help if the container holding map in bootstrap model be of fixed width and height?

Comment: I don't think it would affect my issue, I'm curious as to why my modal isn't refreshing so the google-map can show correctly.

Comment: The map UI comes up so I know the issue isnt a sizing related one, I just can't get it to refresh when the modal comes up

Comment: Checked your code, `on('shown.bs.modal'` should your code to work !

Comment: code snippet not opening the model.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy what do you mean with `mapNum` variable ?

Comment: @Zl3n Since its initializing two maps I'm using that in place of #map1 and #map2

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy I don't find the error, however, you should use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false instead of http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Found the Answer!

I missed something in the console earlier which was:
`map not defined`

Which meant the solution was to take the map variable from within the initialize function and move it outside of it.

### Old

```
function initialize(mapNum) {
  var map;
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.676,-70.786);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
}
```

### New

```
var map;

function initialize(mapNum) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.676,-70.786);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
 }
```